# Походження слова "бритванка"

Tags: історія-мови, словотворення

Я певний час живу у Львові, і мене цікавило як утворилося слово бритванка. Знаю що воно повязане з присутністю ут польського коріння, і є діалектним. 
и може хтось поділитись ісотрією цього слова?

Comment: Було б непогано навести польське коріння чи вказати значення слова.

Comment: І виправити одруки.

Answer (score 5):

«Бритванка» – це деко, лист, листик, посудина виготовлена зі скляного чи керамічного листа із загнутими краями та невисоким бортиком, для смаження та випікання їжі; [форма для випікання хліба в печі](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D2%91%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8#%D0%91).

[image]

Вочевидь, це слово запозичене з польської, від *brytfanna* `[brɨtˈfãnːa]`, значення те саме. Польске ж *brytfanna*, в свою чергу, теж [є запозиченням](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/brytfanna) з якогось німецького діалекту, в сучасній стандартній німецькій йому відповідають *breit* («широкий») + *Pfanne* («сковорода»), англійським етимологічним відповідником було б «broad pan».

Я написав «вочевидь», оскільки українська й польська одночасно не мають контакту з таким діалектом німецької, звідки це слово потрапило до польської.